# Evaluation of the integral $\int \cos\omega t\ln\cos\omega t\,dt$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration, logarithms

I am trying to evaluate an integral of the form

$$ \int \cos\left(\omega t\right) \ln \cos\left(\omega t\right)  dt$$

and am unsure how to proceed.

I rewrote it as:

$$ \textrm{Re} \left\{\int dt \; e^{i\omega t} i \omega t \right\}$$

which evaluates to

$$ \textrm{Re} \left\{\frac{1}{\omega}e^{i\omega t}\left(\omega t + i\right)\right\} $$

The problem is I'm not sure what the imaginary argument to  $\cos \left( \omega t + i\right) $ means and so I wonder both if my approach is correct and if there is an alternative approach.

Comment: $\cos{i} = \cosh{1}$

Comment: I am afraid your first step is wrong. Try integrating by parts instead. This will take you to $\int \sin^2/\cos$ which is ok.

Comment: @julien-- to make sure I get the hint, this is so I can reduce that equation to just that of the log cosine?

Comment: Also, may I ask why my first step is wrong?

Comment: Your second step is ok. For the first one $\mbox{Re}(e^{i\omega t}i\omega t)=-\omega t \sin (\omega t)$. So that's not your initial integrand at all. For IBP, set $u=\ln\cos$ and $dv=\cos dt$.

Comment: @julien I still don't understand my error in the first step. $ \textrm{Re } e^{ix}$ is $\cos x$ and so isn't $\log \cos x$ then the same as $\textrm{Re } \log e^{ix}$?

Comment: If $\cos x>0$ (whch is the case here), $\ln \cos x=\ln \mbox{Re}(e^{ix})=\log  \mbox{Re}(e^{ix}) $ for any determination of $\log$ of the complex logarithm. But $\mbox{Re}$ does not commute with any complex logarithm. What is true is $\mbox{Re} \log z=\ln |z|$. In particular, $\mbox{Re} \log e^{ix}=\ln |e^{ix}|=\ln 1=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate by parts:

$$\begin{align}\int dx \, \cos{x} \, \log{(\cos{x})} &= \sin{x} \, \log{(\cos{x})} + \int dx \frac{\sin^2{x}}{\cos{x}}\\ &= \sin{x} \, \log{(\cos{x})}  - \sin{x} + \int dx \, \sec{x}\\ &= \sin{x} \, \log{(\cos{x})}  - \sin{x} + \log{(\sec{x} + \tan{x})} + C\end{align}$$